# return value and print it in <Text> Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function, promise

Having this function

```
const IsFollowing = async (followID) =>{
  const { data:follow } =await client.query({
    query: QUERY2,
    variables: {
      user_id: userID,
      follow_id: followID
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });
  console.log('RESPONSE', JSON.stringify(follow, null, 2));
  return follow.isFollowing
}
```

which only return **true** or **false** I want to get this value and use it in a Text Component like this

```
<Text style={tailwind('text-sm text-blue-500')}>{IsFollowing(item.item._id) == true ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'}</Text>
```

But no matter what, it always returns only true, even if the value in function is false

Comment: Why you put `async` function inside your Text component ? This will be executed during every render. Instead better use `useEffect` to execute it during an initial rendering or based on the given dependencies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is `async` which means it returns a promise.
You don't use return values of promises in a way you described. Even if you did, you should not make side effects (e.g. data fetching) in render. `useEffect` is for that.

So you can move that function `IsFollowing` inside an `useEffect` (*with the right dependencies*), and then update a boolean variable in state. Then based on that boolean variable you can decide whether to render `follow` or `unfollow`.